# ListView with custom selector

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, selector

I would like when I select an Item, the color name change.
But my issue is that the text changes but the time and do not keep account and does not change color, put only the text in bold and when I select an other Item, before item become again as it was in the beginning.

**list_selector.xml**

```
<item android:drawable="@color/android:transparent" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/android:transparent" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/android:transparent"/>
```

**list_view.xml**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"/>
```

**row_selector.xml**

```
<item android:drawable="@color/col" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/coll" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/colll" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
```

**print_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/row_selector">
```

I would like to know how I can save the state of my row when she was selected and how I can change this selected color ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rowback" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/rowback_selected" />
<item android:state_selected="true" android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/rowback_selected" />
<item android:state_window_focused="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rowback" />
```

its working for me

Comment: Use what? Please complete the answer or delete it.